# wpf ribbon control with custom controls

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

This control has been in pre-release so long I was wondering:

1) is anyone using it for production apps or do you buy 3rd party?
2) how much of your ribbon do you typically do in code vs. xaml?
3) can you put custom / user controls inside of it?
4) any favorite helpful links and / or caveats?

Cheers,
Berryl

I just found this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393355/does-anyone-ever-use-the-ribbon-control). Sorry if too much duplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using it for an internal app with mixed results. I use a mix of XAML and code depending on the situation. For example, I load in different menus depending on who the user is.

It has some bugs that make it dangerous for production use. For example, it goes haywire if you don't set the minimum width on the form to a large enough value. So unless this is a limited distribution, internal application I would wait at least until the next beta.

P.S. If you hear of a good third-party alternative please let me know.

Comment: I've used the devexpress winforms ribbon control with success. If their WPF version is anything like it, it should work well.

Comment: I find your timing to be rather amusing. Microsoft just released a new version of their ribbon control that fixes all the bugs that I thought were dangerous.